# Enabling core files on CentOS 8.1

Tags: centos, systemd, ulimit, core-dump

I am trying to debug a broken application that renders X11 windows.  I am running CentOS 8.1.

I have followed the [instructions per Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/developer_guide/debugging-crashed-application) on enabling core dumps.

1. I have enabled `DefaultLimitCORE=infinity` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`
2. I rebooted the machine
3. I set `ulimit -c unlimited`

When I try to run my application :

```
$ /usr/local/some/broken_executable
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-aps003'
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't see the core file generated either in the current working directory or in my home directory.  I also tried uncommenting the `#DumpCore=yes` line in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and rebooting the machine.

**Question**

1. What am I missing here? I just want to be able to generate core files for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 6):

Your core dumps are probably in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump` (unless you've changed your `systemd` configuration to put them somewhere else).  Use `coredumpctl list` to see what core dumps are available, and `coredumpctl dump` to extract them. See [more info about coredumpctl](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/coredumpctl.1.html)